# why does including html files not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Including of html pages to another html pages. It is working properly but the problem is it does not include files immediately when we run the program or when we refresh or when we enter to the next page it is taking time to include the files for about
2-3seconds. You can Re-load the page to check this issue
Can anyone solve this problem .

Here is the code:-
`HTML code:`

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- To includ meta links and css files -->
    <meta include-html="include/links.html">
    
    <script src="js/include.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- To includ header -->
    <div include-html="include/navbar.html"></div>
    <h2 class="p-5">This files are including but it is not working immediately it takes 2-3seconds of time to load the css files and bootstrap files.
    </h2>
    <h4 class="p-5"> You can Re-load the page to check this issue <br> Please check this.</h4>
     <!-- To include footer -->
    <div include-html="include/footer.html"></div>
    
    <script>
        includeHTML();
    </script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`style.css:`

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'poppins';
}

.nav-item .nav-link
{
    color: red;
}
.nav-item .nav-link.active
{
    color: blue;
}
.logo-space
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

`Included Header Footer and Meta links and css files:`
`navbar.html:`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white  shadow">
  <div class="container font-Nunito">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <!-- <img src="images/icons-2/outdoor.png" alt="logo" > -->
      <i class="fab fa-joomla logo-space"></i>Logo
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<i class="arrow down"></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right fade-down" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">product-1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">product-2</a>
          </div>
        </li>
       
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

`footer.html:`

```
<footer class="footer bg-dark p-5">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="copyright">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center text-light text-md-start mb-3 mb-md-0">
                    &copy; <a class="border-bottom text-light" href=""
                        target="_self">www.abc.in</a>, All Right
                    Reserved.Designed By <br> <a class="border-bottom text-light" target="_blank"
                        href="">XYZ Technologies</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

`links.html:`

```
    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!-- Mobile Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <!-- Site Metas -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Title bar -->
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Google Web Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

    <!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css"    rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Template Stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this is js file-include.js:

```
// include
function includeHTML() {
    var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
    /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      elmnt = z[i];
      /*search for elements with a certain attribute:*/
      file = elmnt.getAttribute("include-html");
      if (file) {
        
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = 
this.responseText;}
            if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not 
found.";}
            /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
            elmnt.removeAttribute("include-html");
            includeHTML();
          }
        }      
        xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
        xhttp.send();
        /*exit the function:*/
    return;
  }
}
```

};

Comment: You are including your include-links in the head. That doesnt work. You need to include your links in the include-navbar

Comment: @Brad that isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I won`t give You complete answer cause I read about this a few week ago, but what is important here? The answer is **place**. You have to insert those files in correct place, because right now your pages load when you redirect to them. Instead of Your pages should load when the main page is loading. They should be "ready for action"

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but, I am not getting where to place. If you know it plz let me know so that it would help me out